# Docker Spring Boot with Postgres works but not with logback.xml

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, logback

I'm new to Docker and I have a Spring Boot app which uses a logback DB appender. Everything worked fine while working locally. Then I created a dockerized Postgres DB and it worked.
But when I tried to use docker compose to build everything together, logback started acting up.
These are my files:

application.properties (localhost was removed and sent via environment variables when dockerizing)

```
server.port=8082
spring.cache.cache-names=InterestCache

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quote_service
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:./scripts/logback-init.sql
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8082
COPY target/challenge-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar challenge.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/challenge.jar"]
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="stdout"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="db" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClass>
<!--            This was localhost:5432 up until dockerizing-->
            <url>jdbc:postgresql://psql-db:5432/quote_service</url>
            <user>admin</user>
            <password>admin</password>
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
        <appender-ref ref="db" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  psql-db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: psql-db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=quote_service
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  challenge:
    container_name: challenge_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://psql-db:5432/quote_service
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=admin
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - psql-db
```

If logback-spring.xml is not present, everything works fine. As soon as logback.xml is created I get this error (the error message is tricky but it's telling it can't connect):

```
challenge_app  | Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
challenge_app  | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:logback-spring.xml
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:245)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:187)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
challenge_app  |        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:356)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
challenge_app  |        at com.alejo.challenge.ChallengeApplication.main(ChallengeApplication.java:16)
challenge_app  |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
challenge_app  |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
challenge_app  |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
challenge_app  |        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
challenge_app  | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DBAppender cannot function if the JDBC driver does not support getGeneratedKeys method *and* without a specific SQL dialect
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.db.DBAppenderBase.start(DBAppenderBase.java:60)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender.start(DBAppender.java:92)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.postHandle(AppenderModelHandler.java:84)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:257)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:208)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator.processModel(SpringBootJoranConfigurator.java:122)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:170)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
challenge_app  |        at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:279)
challenge_app  |        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:242)
challenge_app  |        ... 31 more
```

I've tried setting url as: localhost:5432, 127.0.01:5432, psql-db:5432 but everytime it fails.
Please, I'm out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

Got it to work. Problem was Spring Boot App was coming in too early and db wasn't fully ready, this change fixed the issue:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  psql-db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: psql-db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=quote_service
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U admin -d quote_service
      interval: 5s

  challenge:
    container_name: challenge_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://psql-db:5432/quote_service
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=admin
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      psql-db:
        condition: service_healthy
```